# How to unit test an abstract class method that depends on equals() with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to test an abstract class in Java, and I have a method which depends on `equals()` to provide a result.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {

    public boolean isCanonical() {
        return toCanonical() == this;
    }

    public T toCanonical() {
        T asCanonical = asCanonical();
        if (equals(asCanonical)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) this;
        }
        return asCanonical;
    }

    protected abstract T asCanonical();
}
```

As you can see the `toCanonical()` method compare itself with `asCanonical` build calling the abstract method `asCanonical()`.

To test this I need to create an empty implementation of my abstract class and make mockito calls real methods for the two implemented method and return my own classes for the asCanonical().

```
BaseClass aCanonicalClass;
BaseClass aNonCanonicalClass;

@Mock
BaseClass sut;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // these are the methods under test, use the real ones
    Mockito.when(sut.isCanonical())
            .thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.when(sut.toCanonical())
            .thenCallRealMethod();
}
```

Normally if this wasn't the `equals()` method I would just do this:

```
@Test
public void test_isCanonical_bad() {
    // test true
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aNonCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertTrue(sut.isCanonical());

    // test false
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aNonCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertFalse(sut.isCanonical());
}
```

Which give this error:

> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
>     when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>    Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
> ```

One of Mockito limitations is that it doesn't allow to mock the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

As a workaround I just pass itself when I want to test the condition `equals() = true` and another random object when I want to test the condition `equals() = false`.

```
@Test
public void test_isCanonical() {
    // test true
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(sut);
    Assert.assertTrue(sut.isCanonical());

    // test false
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertFalse(sut.isCanonical());
}
```

But this test pass even if I change the implementation to this:

```
    public T toCanonical() {
        T asCanonical = asCanonical();
        if (this == asCanonical) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) this;
        }
        return asCanonical;
    }
```

or even this:

```
    public T toCanonical() {
        return asCanonical();
    }
```

which is wrong! Comparison should be done with equals. Doing so by reference is not the same thing.

Things gets impossible to test when I get to the `toCanonical()` method:

```
@Test
public void test_toCanonical_bad() {
    // test canonical
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aNonCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertSame(sut, sut.toCanonical());

    // test non-canonical
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aNonCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(true);
    Mockito.when(sut.equals(aCanonicalClass))
            .thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(sut, sut.toCanonical());
    Assert.assertSame(aCanonicalClass, sut.toCanonical());
}
```

This of course doesn't work, and doesn't really makes sense to apply the same workaround because I would just test that the return value of the function is the one of `asCanonical()`:

```
@Test
public void test_toCanonical() {
    // test canonical
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(sut);
    Assert.assertSame(sut, sut.toCanonical());

    // test non-canonical
    Mockito.when(sut.asCanonical())
            .thenReturn(aCanonicalClass);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(sut, sut.toCanonical());
    Assert.assertSame(aCanonicalClass, sut.toCanonical());
}
```

Both test are pointless because of the fact I can't mock the result of `equals()`.

Is there a way to test at least `equals()` is being called with the object I gave it? (spy it)

Is there any other way to test this?

> **EDIT**: this is a semplification of the actual code I'm working with.
>
> I modified the example code to at least show the `toCanonical()` and `asCanonical()` methods are supposed to return instances of the same class (and not just any class)
>
> I want to test the base class here. Only the concrete implementation know how to build an actual canonical class (`asCanonical()`) or check if this class is equal to a canonical class (`equals()`). And please note that `toCanonical()` return ITSELF if it is equals to the canonical version of itself. Again `equals != same`.
>
> The actual implementations are immutable classes. And since they are many and this code is the same for everyone i put it in a base class.

Comment: I don't really understand why can't you create non-empty implementation of `BaseClass` and place all the necessary test logic there? Currently it looks like you forbade yourself to setup test without Mockito for some reason.

Comment: this is simplified code from my ACTUAL code that narrowed it down as much as I could to ask the question. I do not have a single implementation of `BaseClass` and to test my abstract class is doing what it is supposed to do I must test an empty implementation. If a subclass want to override the `toCanonical()` is free to do so and will have its own tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you test an abstract class? If you really want to test the `toCanonical` method (which is not `final`, so you can override it later) you can instantiate a temp concrete class and test it. That is way easier then using Mockito and other stuff.

Ie:

```
@Test
public void myAwesomeTest() {
    // Arrange
    BaseClass test = new BaseClass<String>() {
       // provide concrete implementation
       protected String asCanonical() {
             return "Foo";
       }
    };

    // Act
    String result = test.toCanonical("Bar");

    // Assert

}
```

Once the simple case works, you can extract the creation of `baseclass` into a factory method ie `MakeBaseClass(String valueToReturnForAsCanonical` and write more tests.

Using Spy's are handy if you are in some regions of untested code and you have no way to stub out parts or create some seams in the code. In this case I think you can suffice with writing the boilerplate yourself instead of relying on some magic by Mockito.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to test the `toCanonical()` function.

The job of the function is to call `asCanonical()` and if the returned value is `equals()` to itself return itself, otherwise return the value produced. Only the concrete class know how to procude a canonical version or knows when two classes are identical.

I've edited my question to be closer to the actual code I have (this is of course a semplification).

Comment: check my edit, I added the other part, the `toCanonical()` function testing and fixed the semplified example

Comment: The test calls `toCanonical()` which in turn calls `asCanonical`. Regardless of how, you should still be able to instantiate a concrete class and test against it. Or, use an anonymous class.